# Is possible to know the used and limit heap js memory size in firefox and safari?

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser, memory-leaks

In Chrome there's a non-standard API called performance.memory, which helps to know the current usage and limit of the Heap JS Memory, but in Firefox and Safari that's not possible. Do you know another way to find or calculate those values?

Thank you so much!

I can't try to make my code cleaner, I'm just avoiding to make some calculations if the current memory heap is so high.